# Dynamic and Conditional Column Updating in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

This is what my data.table looks like. The last column New_Amount is my desired column.

```
 StartingAmount<-10
 library(data.table)    
 dt <- fread('
                 Level   Interest  New_Amount
                    0      .5        10
                    1      .5        15
                    0      .5        15
                    0      .3        15
                    1      .2        18
                    0      .4        18
                    1      .5        27
        ')
```

Lets say I am starting with $10. For each row where Level =1, I want to calculate my new amount after adding in interest. So for the second row where Level =1, my New_Amount is 10+(10*.5) =15. In the 5th row where Level=1, my New_Amount is 15+(15*.2)=18. I am going to ignore rows where Level=0 and just carry the last observation forward.

This is my attempt:

```
dt[, NewAmount:= ifelse(Level==1,StartingAmount+StartingAmount*Interest,0)]
  dt[, NewAmount:= ifelse(Level==1, New_Amount + New_Amount*Interest , NA)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumprod` on the `Interest` column which you can multiply with the `Level` column to determine if extra interest should be added to the previous one:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, New_Amount := StartingAmount * cumprod(1 + Level * Interest)][]

#   Level Interest New_Amount
#1:     0      0.5         10
#2:     1      0.5         15
#3:     0      0.5         15
#4:     0      0.3         15
#5:     1      0.2         18
#6:     0      0.4         18
#7:     1      0.5         27
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Its a great solution.